# Вызов(генерация) событий в Angular 2/4

Tags: angular2, angular4

Подскажите кто знает

Как в Angular 2/4 генерировать (искусственно создавать) события аналогично jquery-методам таким-как `trigger()`, `click()` и тд.

Comment: `EventEmitter<T>`

Comment: Допустим у нас есть <button id="btn-1">Click1</button> и <button id="btn-2">Click2</button> как сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопке с id="btn-2" генерировался(вызывался) клик на кнопке c id="btn-1"??? Какой код должен быть в компонентах этих кнопок

Comment: Для этого надо перестать мыслить категориями html элементов, и начать мыслить категориями цельных компонентов.

Comment: Пусть эти две кнопки находятся в одном шаблоне. Клик на одной должен вызывать событие клика у другой. Пока не соображу как это сделать...?

Comment: А что должно происходить при клике второй? если в шаблоне будет что-то вроде: `<button id="btn-1" (click)="func1()">Click1</button><button id="btn-2"  (click)="func2()">Click2</button>` - то самое простое, вызвать `func2` напрямую в `func1`

Comment: Я наверно начал немного издалека) Вообщем ситуация следующая: Есть шаблон с формой и есть кнопка submit(или необязательно submit) которая должна отправить эту форму, но она находится не внутри тега form, а за её пределами, пока не знаю как связать событие клика по этой кнопке с событием отправки формы. То-есть нужно запустить событие submit у формы по клику на кнопке находящейся НЕ внутри тега form Я с Angular-(ом) только начал знакомится, прошу отнестись с пониманием)))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67045/discussion-between-grundy-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Касательно форм вариантов много, например:

```
<form .... (ngSubmit)="myFormSubmitHandler()" #f1>
    <input....>
    <input....>
</form>
<button (click)="f1.submit()">
```

или банально вызвать обработчик минуя сабмит как таковой

```
<form ....>
    <input....>
    <input....>
</form>
<button (click)="myFormSubmitHandler()">
```

Можно придумать еще более извращенные способы при желани :)
Но лучше все таки почитать туториал https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте так 
При нажатии на батн должна будет кликаться кнопа

кнопа
батн[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста оформите нормально свой вариант ответа. Код приведите в тело ответа. Либо дайте ссылку на codepen если хотите показать работу кода в интерактиве.